# AMP stories - close button on last page - bookend.json

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

In the AMP story documentation: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#bookend-json-endpoint

There is a visible 'x' on the last page in the upper-right corner (presumably to close it): 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ampproject/amphtml/master/extensions/amp-story/img/related-articles.gif

How can I get the 'x' to display on my story?

It is not mentioned in the bookend.json file configuration in the documentation and doesn't display 'out of the box'.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

The 'X' is not configurable. The screenshot is from an older version of the Story runtime and is no longer up-to-date.